# Storing width values before animation records post animation values

Tags: javascript, jquery

Its getting a bit late so excuse me if I am making a stupid mistake. For some reason the following code:

```
$(".myClass").each(function(){
    widths[$(this).attr("id")] = $(this).width();   
    if ($(this).attr("id")  != $(clickedExpand).attr("id"))
    {
        $(this).animate({
            width: '10px'
        });
    }

});
```

The array is initialized as

```
var widths = new Array();
```

earlier in the code. For some reason, despite the fact that I am recording the the widths before the animation begins, I am getting post-animation values in the array. It seems as though the animation finishes and then the values get recorded. I have tried to take it out of the function and wrap it in another .each but I am getting the same result.

Any help is would be greatly appreciated!

entire code:

```
var slateWidths = {};
$(".slateExpand").click(function(){
    var clickedExpand = $(this).closest(".slate");

    $(".slate").each(function(){
        slateWidths[$(this).attr("id")] = $(this).outerWidth();   
        if ($(this).attr("id")  != $(clickedExpand).attr("id"))
        {
            $(this).animate({
                width: '10px'
            });
            $(this).find($('.slateExpand')).hide();
        }

    });

    $(this).text("Restore");
    $(this).removeClass("slateExpand").addClass("slateRestore");
    $(".slateRestore").on("click",function(){

        $(".slate").each(function()
        {
            alert(slateWidths[$(this).attr("id")]);
            //var width = slateWidths[$(this).attr("id")];
            $(this).animate({
                width: slateWidths[$(this).attr("id")]
                });
        });
    });
});
```

Comment: Never use `new Array()`, and don't use arrays when you actually want objects. (`var widths = {};`)

Comment: Interesting... how come? Also, the issue is still there unfortunately :(

Comment: When do you get the wrong values? Directly from the `width()` method, or do you set/get them somewhere else? Show us the whole code

Comment: I have posted the entire code. I am getting the new, post animation values when I try to reverse the width animation, thus nothing happens.

Comment: Seems to be working for me: http://jsfiddle.net/joplomacedo/8wd59/1/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
// first of all save all widths for all .slate
var slateWidths = {};
$(".slate").each(function(){
    slateWidths[$(this).attr("id")] = $(this).width();
});

$(".slateExpand").click(function(){
    var $slate = $(this).closest('slate');    

    if($slate.hasClass('hidden')) {

        $slate.animate({
            width: slateWidths[$slate.attr('id')]
        });
        $(this).text("hide");
        $slate.removeClass("hidden")        
    }else{

        $slate.animate({
            width: '10px'
        });
        $(this).text("Restore");
        $slate.addClass("hidden")
    }    
});
```

Comment: This a great solution, but I need it to be saved on click because the initial widths are not constant but may change depending on what you do with the slates. However, I found the solution, you simply need to unbind() the event. I thank you very much for taking the time to solve this. If you want, you can throw up the solution and ill give you the check off :)

Comment: In other words, the click bind was still applied to the div even if the class changed so you need to remove it on click.

Comment: As you can see i am not messing with `slateExpand` class anywhere :) Anyways, i am happy you solved your poblem

Answer (score 0):

Ok, if you come across a similar issue, there is an easy solution. The issue is that the click has not be unbound the event from the div despite the class change. As a result, it first reruns the code that records the widths. This causes the animation to not play since now the previous widths are the same as the current ones. To solve this, simply add

```
   $("theDiv").unbind("click);
```

to remove the event handler. This will prevent the click event which is for the previous class from firing.